# Adjusting Component size in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a viewstack with 3 items in it. Now my problem is that I want all these components to be of the same size. Its simply enough to do this manually but is there any other way of setting the size for all the components at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set the 'left/right/top/bottom' styles for that items.

Answer (score 0):

There are (roughly) two big-time ways to go about this that I see right off the bat:

1. Basically you bind those components' width values to one variable, and their height values to another variable.  Use the same two variables for all of your components.  For example:

   ```
   <mx:Script>
       <![CDATA[
           [Bindable]
           private var m_nWidth:Number = 50;

           [Bindable]
           private var m_nHeight:Number = 50;

           private function someFunc():void
           {
               m_nWidth = 100;
               m_nHeight = 200;
               // uic1, uic2, and uic3 are all now 100 x 200
           }
          ]]>
   </mx:Script>
   <mx:ViewStack id="vs">
       <mx:UIComponent id="uic1" width="{m_nWidth}" height="{m_nHeight}"/>
       <mx:UIComponent id="uic2" width="{m_nWidth}" height="{m_nHeight}"/>
       <mx:UIComponent id="uic3" width="{m_nWidth}" height="{m_nHeight}"/>
   </mx:ViewStack>
   ```
2. You could also set percentage-style strings on their width and height attributes, making them scale with regards to the size of the ViewStack.  For example:

   ```
   <mx:Script>
       <![CDATA[
           private static const WIDTH:String = "50%";
           private static const HEIGHT:String = "25%";

           private function someFunc():void
           {
               vs.width = 200;
               vs.height = 800;
               // uic1, uic2, and uic3 are all now 100 x 200
           }
          ]]>
   </mx:Script>
   <mx:ViewStack id="vs">
       <mx:UIComponent id="uic1" width="{WIDTH}" height="{HEIGHT}"/>
       <mx:UIComponent id="uic2" width="{WIDTH}" height="{HEIGHT}"/>
       <mx:UIComponent id="uic3" width="{WIDTH}" height="{HEIGHT}"/>
   </mx:ViewStack>
   ```

Answer (score -3):

not sure if you already got the answer

but what i read was that you could set the main application to be 100% for bott height and width. for the viewstack you set it as 100% also.  it should resize the children accordingly

or you can use actionscript percentHeight and percentWidth to set the property

Comment: He didn't mention the main application's size or the figure 100%.